# Error in Unshelve migrate of TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-power-tools

I tried to use unshelve /migrate command of tfpt to move the shelves of one branch to another. I have used the command which is given below,

```
 tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"$/Project name/branch name" /target:"$/Project name/branch name" "shelvesetname"
```

But gives the error as "Unable to determine the workspace"
Is there any solution for this?
Can anyone give the examples of how to give target and source paths? 
How to do unshelve with migrate in Visual studio 2012 interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are both branches mapped in a workspace on your local machine?
If not, map them.

If so, are you running the command from within the workspace?

i.e. "$/Project name/branch name" is mapped to "C:\TFS\Project Name\branch name" 
so run the command from "C:\TFS\Project Name\branch name"

Finally you could try running `tf workspaces` before running the command

Comment: Yes it worked.  Whether the "unshelve" with "migrate" option is there in Visual studio 2012 interface, instead of command lines?